# How to send files into docker container via requests?

Tags: python, json, docker, flask

I am using docker for a data-science project. The docker image contains a python code that reads a file(image file), processes it, and generates a vector of floats as an output.

I am using flask micro-framework for a user to interact with the container. Here is the server-side code (running inside the container). It is of course buggy!

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Api
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

@app.route('/process_image', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def process_image():
  params = request.json
  with open(params["file_name"]. "r") as f:
    # the above access to a file in host machine from docker container,
    # will definetly lead to an access error.

    # do some processing
    pass
```

Here is the client-side code

```
import requests
file_name = "some-path/image.jpg" # on the host machine
requests.get('http://0.0.0.0:5000/process_image/', json={"file_name": file_name})
```

What is the right way to pass a file via requests to the container? I am looking at a solution where the client-side code is minimal and the user must be able to send a file stored at any location in the host-machine.

I am new to docker as well as web-programming, I would appreciate any feedback/suggestion. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean that you want to upload a file to the webserver for analysis? If so, please see https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack I see what you mean. Looks like file upload might solve my problem. Let me try it out in my code. I will soon update you on this.